# How do I simplify this expression about factorization?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, fractions

I am trying to simplify this

$$\frac{9x^2 - x^4}  {x^2 - 6x +9}$$

The solution is

$$\frac{-x^2(x +3)}{x-3} = \frac{-x^3 - 3x^2}{x-3} $$

I have done $$\frac{x^2(9-x^2)}{(x-3)(x-3)} = \frac{x^2(3-x)(3+x)}{(x-3)(x-3)} $$

but I do not find a way to simplify

How can I simplify to get the answer?

I have to use

$${(a +b)(a -b)} = {a^2 - b^2} $$
$${(a +b)^2} = {a^2 + 2ab+b^2} $$
$${(a -b)^2} = {a^2 - 2ab+b^2} $$

Comment: You have done all the hard work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that $(3-x)=-(x-3)$. Simplify accordingly.

Comment: Oh I did not see that , x^2 - (x-3)(x +3)/(x -3)(x-3), so I can obtain the answer, thanks for answering

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
9x^2-x^4=-x^2(x^2-9)=-x^2(x-3)(x+3).
$$
Thus, we have that
$$
\frac{9x^2-x^4}{x^2-6x+9}=\frac{-x^2(x-3)(x+3)}{(x-3)^2}=-x^2\left(\frac{x+3}{x-3}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering I did not see that until the first answer

Comment: Which is wrong, since $x^2-6x+9=(x-3)^2$ and not $(x-3)(x+3)$

Comment: @Learner My initial answer was wrong. I've corrected it now (what Demosthene pointed out was right).

Comment: @induktio Better :)

Comment: @Demosthene Thanks for pointing it out. `*tips fedora*`